# Unsupervized NER + sequence tagging to extract attributes from product descriptions

Tags: data-mining, feature-extraction

I am trying to extract attribute values from product descriptions in an unsupervised way.

For example, given the product title "Variety pack fillet mignon and porterhouse steak dog food (12 count)", I want to extract values for "12 count" -> size, "fillet mignon" -> flavor, etc.

If I use word2vec for word embeddings, what are the ways to go about word combinations, like "fillet mignon"? It seems to me that I would need to perform some type of BIO / BIOE tagging, since I am working with a dataset that has no tags.

What are the ways to approach this? Is there any technique that can do unsupervised sequence tagging?